# Start numbering from Introduction not from \listoftables?

Tags: numbering, page

I am using Overleaf for TeX editor. I want to start numbering from **Introduction** , but instead starts from `\listoftables`. How can I continue counting `\listoftables` with Roman and start Arabic numbering from the Introduction?

The **main** proceeds as below:

```
\begin{document}

% new lengths for a harmonized width of the plots
\newlength{\plotwidth}
\setlength{\plotwidth}{0.7\columnwidth}
\newlength{\plotheight}
\setlength{\plotheight}{0.66\plotwidth}
\newlength{\semiwidth}
\setlength{\semiwidth}{0.35\columnwidth}
\newlength{\semiheight}
\setlength{\semiheight}{0.66\semiwidth}

% the titlepage
\pagenumbering{alph}
\pagestyle{empty}
\include{sections/titlepage}

% the preface
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\include{sections/abstract}
\include{sections/task}
\include{sections/declaration}

% the table of contents and the lists of figures and tables

\tableofcontents
\include{sections/notation}
\include{sections/acronyms}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

% the actual content
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{sections/introduction}
\include{sections/body}
\include{sections/implementation}
\include{sections/experiments}
\include{sections/results}
\include{sections/discussion}

% the bibliography
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}   % only numbers
\bibliography{literature}

% the appendix
\appendix
\include{sections/appendix}

% the theses
\pagestyle{empty}   
\include{sections/statements}

\end{document}

% end of file
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You need `\clearpage` before "the actual content".  `\pagenumbering` takes effect immediately on the currently in-process page.

Comment: Welcome! What kind of article class do you use? If you use a `book` class, you can use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. Could you provide a compilable MWE (minimal working example), so that we can see what is going on?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your suggestion worked. Thank you very much! I apologize for late reply!

Comment: @Taunch The first thing I tried was \frontmatter and \mainmatter. I could not get to work. The article class I am using is "Thesis". Maybe that is the reason that it did not work. Nevertheless, I am no expert, so it could be that I did not use them properly?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the suggestion from @barbarabeeton. Using `\clearpage`
will keep the counting as roman until the end of `\listoftables`.

After change:

```
% the table of contents and the lists of figures and tables
\tableofcontents
\include{sections/notation}
\include{sections/acronyms}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

% the actual content
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{sections/introduction}
\include{sections/body}
\include{sections/implementation}
\include{sections/experiments}
\include{sections/results}
\include{sections/discussion}
```